# Javascript - clear an attribute of an element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML element:

```
<a id="link" href="javascript : void(0);" onclick="jsFunction();">Some Text</a>
```

And when a button is clicked I want the **onclick** attribute to be cleared. Something like

```
<a id="link" href="javascript : void(0);" onclick="">Some Text</a>
```

I tried doing this way :

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick="";
```

which didn't work.

Comment: Is it because you wrote `onlclick` or was that a typo in this post?

Comment: @Raj BD: This will not work. Use `removeAttribute()` See my answer below.

Comment: What is your actual goal? To remove the call to jsFunction or to remove the attribute in the HTML DOM?

Comment: @JulienCh. I just want to make sure that that the function is not called twice..

Comment: You should use `document.getElementById('link').onclick="";` no need to modify the HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `removeAttribute()`

```
document.getElementById('link').removeAttribute('onclick');
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/FZEgs/)